Using R Crosstalk, Plotly and DT, Is there a way of filtering a plotly using a table instead of highlighting selected values
Currently a Plotly visual and DT table can be linked using a Crosslink shared data source such that any selections in the table are highlighted in the plotly visual. Instead of highlighting the selected data, is it possible to filter the plot such the unselected data points are not shown in the plot, and the plot scales to the selected data. I will be using this in a Quarto document, so I can't use Shiny.
A working example of the highlighting option can be found in the following link.
Link to plot highlight example.
For convenience I have copied Leon's accepted answer below as an example of highlighting the data. How can be this changed to filter the data?
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

# Wide format
df_test1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("id1", "id2"),
  item1 = c(0, 4),
  item2 = c(3, 2),
  item3 = c(1, 4),
  item4 = c(3, 4),
  item5 = c(1, NA)
)

# Reshaped to long format
df_test2 <- 
  df_test1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = item1:item5, names_to = "item", values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(item = as.factor(item)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = factor(as.character(value), levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")))

# two shared data objects. Note the group argument. 
# this argument can be any string, as long as it is the same in both 
# datasets:
sd1 <- SharedData$new(df_test1, key = ~id, group = "groupdata")
sd2 <- SharedData$new(df_test2, key = ~id, group = "groupdata")

bscols(
  ggplotly(
      ggplot(sd2, aes(x = value, y = item, group = id)) + 
      geom_path() + 
      geom_point(aes(color = value), size = 3) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top", limits = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")), 
    tooltip = c("x", "y", "group"), height = 600, width = 300),     
  datatable(sd1)
)  


Do you want to filter the table based on points selected in the plot? Or select items in the table to filter the plot? your question is unclear currently

I would like the points in the plot to be filtered based on the selection in the table such that only the filtered points are shown.

Do you just want to hide points corresponding to one line (id1 or id2)? If yes, the answer in this post gives the option to set the opacity of non-selected points to 0.

I don't think that hiding the points will work because the scale will remain the same. There will be a wide range of values used in the y scale and consequently the plot has to auto adjust to the range of the filtered data e.g. Category A might have values in the thousands (1234, 5324, 8743) whereas category B might have much lower values e.g. 1.3, 1.5, 2,3.

Ok, I think it is not possible without an input filter (i.e. with a filter_checkbox input on id, the scale adapts to the filtered data). It doesn't seem possible to filter the data based on the resulting table

Ok Julien. I thought it would be great if a row in a summary table could be selected and this data would be filter in the plot. I know I could do this using Shiny but looks like it can't be done using Quarto. Thanks for your help.
